# Don't understand why print(char + int) causes an error

Tags: python

```
fname3 = input("Enter the Blue print name: ")
import re
with open (fname3) as file:
    fileText=file.read()
q1,q2,q3 = [ int(n) for n in re.findall(": (\d+)",fileText) ]
p1,p2,p3 = re.findall("(.*):",fileText)
qb=q1+q2
qc=q1+q2+q3

print("This BLUEPRINT CONTAINS--------------|")
print(p1+" Questions: "+q1)
```

This code above is giving an error of line: `print(p1+" Questions: "+q1)`
but `print(p1+" Questions: "+p1)` is giving correct output abd also `print("q1")`
but combining them is outputting an error

but gives error `print("questions: "+q1)`
This code opens a txt file which contains the following:

```
Part A: 12 10*2 = 20
Part B: 6 4*5 = 20
Part C: 5 3*10 = 30
```

Comment: _"This code above is giving an error of line . . ."_ - Please post the full, specific traceback you are getting directly into your question.

Comment: @ChristianDeanI didn't get you,  the last line i.e print(p1+" Questions: "+q1) is giving out error

Comment: If you're getting an error, Python is giving you a _traceback_ - a list of errors. Please post those in your question.

Comment: Yes, and you should give a [mcve] showing what error. Also google your error messages.

Comment: @JackMoody the ide force closes, if not I would have mentioned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do this is with something called f-strings (available in Python 3.6+, but the latest version is 3.7):

`print (f"{p1} Questions: {q1}")`

Notice how there is an `f` before the quotes (applies to all types of quotes), and any variable you want has to be in `{}`

Comment: So the "f" automatically does the type conversion?

Comment: Well, if you understand the `str.format` method, this is basically a shorthand. For example, `print (num.format (","))` will print `num` with commas where appropriate (which might differ outside of America). However, `print (f"{num:,}")` makes it obvious that `num` is what's being printed and anything after the `:` gets passed to `str.format`. Also, it helps to avoid pesky spaces that get forgotten when using `+` as you can see it plainly. [Click for more details](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to a string with `str`:

```
print(p1 + " Questions: " + str(q1))
```

Alternatively, simply use multiple arguments when calling `print`:

```
print(p1, "Questions:", q1)
```

Note that the spaces are added automatically with this method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the types of your variables.

`Questions:`, `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are all of type `str`.

Conversely, `q1`, `q2` and `q3` are of type `int`.

The `print` calls work separately because `print` can convert its arguments to `str`. However, you are first trying to add two strings (`p1` and `Questions:`) to an `int` (`q2`), which is what fails.

Rather than naive addition/concatenation, you should prefer `str.format` calls:

`print('{p} Questions: {q}'.format(p=p1, q=q1))`

These make it easier to understand what the string will look like and automatically perform conversion of your arguments.

Comment: the other answer which had been answered first works and since he gave the ans 1st I marked him, I gave an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Python is strongly typed language. In most cases, it does not do any implicit type conversion. Consider, should "5"+7 be 12 or "57"? How about 7+"5"?

On ambiguous cases like this, Python will simply raise error rather than trying to guess what you meant.

You need to do the type conversion explicitly:

```
print(p1+" Questions: "+str(q1))
```

or with Python 3 f-string:

```
print(f"{p1} Questions: {q1}")
```

or print function accepts multiple arguments, that will, by default, be separated by space:

```
print(p1, "Questions:", q1)
```